How to make Pusher trigger another user geolocation coordinates
For a logistic project with a map (Vue3 / Node.js) that shows the delivery person location I would like to trigger another user geolocation coordinates on demand (by pushing a button) so that I don't need to use real-time geolocation tracking on a map, which is quite expensive. It can be done if the delivery user and I are on the same Pusher-enabled SPA page. But if the user changes page or refreshes page while being on another viewing page this cannot be done anymore.
Is there a way for Pusher to remain alert on triggering events no matter which page we are on, or is there a better way to make this work?
Thanks in advance guys
I have tried to send API call vie clicking button to the server which triggers push to the channel subscribers, this is Node.js server code:
app.get('/pusher', (req, res) => {     pusher.trigger("xana-channel", "my-event", {         message: "Sent from the frontend via API and pushed to subscribers"     });     res.send() })
